# Problema al crear un test para un file.exists() interno

Tags: junit-5

Un favor estoy tratando de realizar un test del siguiente servicio con un metodo de esta caracteristica, si se puede una solución **SIN USAR PowerMockito**

```
@Service
public class MyServ {
 public void descarga(String fichero, String ruta){
        String ficheroN = Paths.get(fichero).normalize().toString();
        String rutaN = Paths.get(ruta).normalize().toString();
        
 File file = new File(rutaN,ficheroN);
        if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("mockedFile.exists(): true");
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("mockedFile.exists(): false");
        }
        }
}
```